# GetExtension method error

Tags: c#, console-application

I'm getting this error:

> would not find a GetExtension method

Code:

```
public static void Main()
{
    string[] arr = {"abc.txt", "asd.TXT","bvc.pdf","fgd.txt","hss.pdf","djhd.xml"};
    var arrp = arr.Select(file=>Path.GetExtension(file).TrimStart('.').ToLower()).GroupBy(x=>x,(ext,extcnt)=>new
    {
        Extension = ext,
        count=extcnt.Count()
    });
    foreach(var v in arrp)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} files(s) with {1} Extension", v.Count,v.Extension );
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Did you add `System.IO` to your project?

Comment: Is your class called `Path` by any chance? Please post a [mcve]. (It's also not clear what this has to do with ASP.NET.)

Comment: Indeed, as the others have said... try System.IO.Path.GetExtension

Comment: what you are getting compile error? The name 'Path' does not exist in the current context? or in LINQ expression tree  /foreach?

Answer (score 0):

First check, do you have added the using statment? `using System.IO;`

Second change your code line:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0} files(s) with {1} Extension", v.Count, v.Extension);
```

to:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0} files(s) with {1} Extension", v.count, v.Extension);
```

i had created a new console application. This example works in my enviroment:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] arr = { "abc.txt", "asd.TXT", "bvc.pdf", "fgd.txt", "hss.pdf", "djhd.xml" };
            var arrp = arr.Select(file => Path.GetExtension(file).TrimStart('.').ToLower()).GroupBy(x => x, (ext, extcnt) => new
            {
                Extension = ext,
                count = extcnt.Count()
            });
            foreach (var v in arrp)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} files(s) with {1} Extension", v.count, v.Extension);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

i get this result:

[image]

> Important: this is a console application! not a asp.net application! (you have added the asp.net tag.. )